# Перенаправление udp трафика средствами iptables

Tags: ubuntu, маршрутизация, vpn, iptables, firewall

Ситуация следующая. Арендовал у хостера VDS на ubuntu 22.04 с белым ip, настроил на нём vpn-server (10.15.0.1), а дома на ПК за натом настроил vpn-client (10.15.0.2). На сервере запустил реверс-прокси (nginx в контейнере), и обращение к ip сервера летает через vpn к клиенту, отдавая страницу с последнего. Теперь к проблеме:
Отправляю netflow трафик на сервер (порт 2055). На нём-же смотрю утилитой iptraf-ng, что приходит на интерфейс ens0 - почти каждую секунду есть netflow-трафик от микротика:

`UDP (1492 bytes) from <ip микротика>:2055 to <ip сервера>:2055 on ens3`

Вроде всё ок. Нужно перенаправить этот-же трафик клиенту. В файле /etc/sysctl.conf раскомментировал строчку `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, перезагрузил, и давай писать в iptables.
Пробовал так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i ens0 --dport 2055 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.15.0.2:2055
```

и так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d <ip сервера> --dport 2055 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.15.0.2:2055
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

даже пробовал делать так, по мануалу для tcp-трафика, только протокол поменял на udp:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp --dport 2055 -m state --state NEW -j DNAT --to 10.15.0.2:2055
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 2055 -j SNAT --to-source 10.15.0.1
```

Но результата нет - я не только не вижу приходящих udp-фрэймов через iptraf-ng на клиенте, но и не вижу исходящих на сервере на интерфейсе tun0.

iptables до изменений имеет вид:

```
iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Таблицы нат:

```
iptables -L -nv -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2879  132K DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Таблицы filter:

```
iptables -L -nv -t filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

В какую сторону копать, правильно ли я понимаю, что данные не улетают, и если да - то как узнать, почему? В качестве транспорта для vpn выбран udp - может ли это оказывать влияние?

Answer (score 0):

Не смог добиться необходимого поведения на ubuntu 22.04 ни через iptables, ни через nftables. Поменял ОС на ubuntu 20.04, там iptables ещё legacy и всё работает без проблем. Применил команду `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp --dport 2055 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.15.0.2` и всё пошло.